# Pseudo-inverse via signular value decomposition in numpy.linalg.lstsq

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, svd

at the risk of using the wrong SE...

My question concerns the `rcond` parameter in `numpy.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond)`. I know it's used to define the cutoff for small singular values in the singular value decomposition when numpy computed the pseudo-inverse of `a`.

But why is it advantageous to set "small" singular values (values below the cutoff) to zero rather than just keeping them as small numbers?

PS: Admittedly, I don't know exactly how the pseudo-inverse is computed and exactly what role SVD plays in that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To determine the rank of a system, you could need compare against zero, but as always with floating point arithmetic we should compare against some finite range. Hitting exactly 0 never happens when adding and subtracting messy numbers.

The (reciprocal) condition number allows you to specify such a limit in a way that is independent of units and scale in your matrix.
You may also opt of of this feature in `lstsq` by specifying `rcond=None` if you know for sure your problem can't run the risk of being under-determined.

The future default sounds like a wise choice from numpy

> FutureWarning: `rcond` parameter will change to the default of machine precision times `max(M, N)` where M and N are the input matrix dimensions

because if you hit this limit, you are just fitting against rounding errors of floating point arithmetic instead of the "true" mathematical system that you hope to model.